# How do l initialize this class instance in Swift Xcode

Tags: swift, ios8

[image]

myTVcontroller is a tableview controller, l want to create this instance in my custom cell to aid with my custom delegation to update a UILabel e.g.

instance.delegate = yes

But l don't know how and what to put inside the brackets, can you show me a sample please.

Answer (score 1):

Init with coder is used when you create instance of UIView (or subclass like table view) from xib/storyboard and this init with coder mostly is override in subclass to do some custom initialisation.

If you want to create table view controller in code use init with style:

```
myTVController(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
```